# Comparing dates in MS Access where date >= '1/1/2016'

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I know this question has been asked several times, but I think this is a bit unique. 
I have a MS Access database that has a DateTime field that I need to compare with a date >= '1/1/2016', or any other date for that matter.

My basic query is as follows

```
SELECT TOP 100 DTime, PEvent, FName, LName FROM EventLogs
```

In order to compare against dates, I know I have to do WHERE Dtime >= #1/1/2016#

The problem is, the Date/Time comparison is automatically entered in another piece of software I'm running, so the syntax cannot be changed.

```
SELECT TOP 100 DTime, PEvent, FName, LName FROM EventLogs WHERE DTime >= '1/1/2016'
```

The entire WHERE clause is automatically entered based on what field I specify as the DateTime field.

What I have tried is the following

```
SELECT TOP 100 CDate(Format([DTime], 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss AM/PM')) AS LogTime, PEvent, FName, LName FROM EventLogs WHERE 'DTime' >= '1/1/2016'
```

This brings back results, but unfortunately it does not correctly compare on the date. Does anyone have an idea how I can accomplish this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance

The connection between the software and the database in an ODBC connection, with ANSI 92 enabled.

Comment: So just for clarification, this bit:   DTime >= '1/1/2016'    is generated automatically and you can not edit it? Correct?

Comment: Why is `'DTime'` in  quotes? Can you expand on what "The problem is, the Date/Time comparison is automatically entered in another piece of software I'm running, so the syntax cannot be changed." means? Does that mean the whole `WHERE DTime >= '1/1/2016'` is added in the other software? What is the other software? How are you making the query in it?

Comment: Correct, the entire 'WHERE DTime >= '1/1/2016'' statement is generated by the other software and cannot be edited. Only the statements prior to the WHERE clause can be edited.  I think it would be easier to focus on generating the correct output in Access rather than dealing with external software. So, I need to create the correct output while using 
`WHERE DTime >= '1/1/2016'` at all times.

Comment: unfortunately `WHERE DTime >= '1/1/2016'` is not syntactically correct. If you can't change that you are kind of SOL.

Comment: There is no way to write the SELECT statement to handle the comparison correctly? What about a different ODBC driver to connect to the MDB file? I'm using the 64 bit Access MDB driver right now with a System DSN.

Comment: How is the `WHERE` clause received? an SQL statement is forever String, a sequence of characters. It could be a String variable or constant in VBA code, or the SQL property of a Query Object. in any case it could be manipulated before execution.

Answer (score 2):

An SQL statement is forever String, a sequence of characters. It could be a String variable or constant in VBA code, or the `SQL` property of a Query Object. In any case it could be manipulated before execution:
In a Query object:

```
MyQuery.SQL=Replace(MyQuery.SQL, "'", "#")
MyQuery.Execute
```

in VBA:

```
Dim Dbs As DAO.Database
Set Dbs = CurrentDB 'Could also be: Set Dbs = OpenDatabase(DatabaseFileLocation)
Dbs.Execute Replace("SELECT TOP 100 DTime, PEvent, FName, LName FROM EventLogs WHERE DTime >= '1/1/2016'", "'", "#")
```

Or could be:

```
Dbs.Execute "SELECT TOP 100 DTime, PEvent, FName, LName FROM EventLogs " & Replace("WHERE DTime >= '1/1/2016'", "'", "#")
```

The Idea is: If Access can run it, Access can modify it beforehand.
If the statement is not modified, the clause will be done on `String` values, not `DateTime` values.

Comment: These options are only suggestions, and could be implemented in a way that better suits your system, just follow the final idea: **If Access can run it, Access can modify it beforehand.**

Answer (score 0):

> Correct, the entire 'WHERE DTime >= '1/1/2016'' statement is generated
>   by the other software and cannot be edited.

As Brad already commented, this is not Access SQL, thus is never going to work.

Your only option is to change the query to a *pass-through* query which will send this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 DTime, PEvent, FName, LName FROM EventLogs WHERE DTime >= '1/1/2016'
```

to the SQL Server which understands the syntax.